# Lie algebras of lie subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\textbf{p}: \widetilde{G} \to G$ be a covering homomorphism of Lie groups $\widetilde{G}$ and $G$ and  $\widetilde{H}$, $p(\widetilde{H})=H$ -- subgroups of $\widetilde{G}$ and $G$ repsectively. It is clear for me that $\textbf{d}_{e}p$ provides the isomorphism of Lie algebras of $\widetilde{G}$ and $G$ just because the kernel of $\textbf{p}$ is dicrete and the fact that any path in $G$ can be lifted.

Then, is it true that $\textbf{Lie}(H)=\textbf{d}_{e}p(\widetilde{H})$? In other words, does it follow that  $\textbf{Lie}(H) \subset \textbf{d}_{e}p(\widetilde{H})$?

P.S. One can assume $\widetilde{H}$ to be normal, thus its  and $H$ 's tangent spaces are really lie algebras.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: $H$ may not be closed in $G$, in which case I'm not sure what you mean by $\mathbf{Lie}(H)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey thank you for your reply.  I was also  confused by that fact, but this is what is written in my lectures, and if I interpret them correctly,  it is just the set of tangent vectors of curves in $H$, which is always the vector space (as $H$ is a group) and lie subalgebra of $Lie(G)$ as $H$  is a normal group...

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$. Then, given $X\in\operatorname{Lie}(G)$, $X\in\operatorname{Lie}(H)$ if and only if$$(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}):\exp(tX)\in H.$$Now, the goal is to prove that, if $X\in\operatorname{Lie}(H)$, then $X\in D_ep\left(\widetilde X\right)$, for some $\widetilde X\in\operatorname{Lie}\left(\widetilde H\right)$. As you know, $D_ep$ is an isomorphism. So, lt $\widetilde X\in\operatorname{Lie}\left(\widetilde G\right)$ be such that $d_ep\left(\widetilde X\right)=X$. Then$$(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}):\exp\left(t\widetilde X\right)\in\widetilde H,$$since\begin{align}p\left(\exp\left(t\widetilde X\right)\right)&=\exp\left(D_ep\left(t\widetilde X\right)\right)\\&=\exp\left(tD_ep\left(\widetilde X\right)\right)\\&=\exp(tX)\\&\in H.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel of $p$ is discrete, the kernel of the restriction of $p$ to $\widetilde H$ is also discrete. To see this let $g\in Kerp_{\mid \widetilde H}$ since $g\in kerp$, there exists an open subset $U$ of $\widetilde G$ such that $U\cap ker p=\{g\}$. $U\cap \widetilde H$ is an open subset of $\widetilde H$,  for the induced topology and $U\cap\widetilde H\subset U\cap \widetilde G=\{g\}$, so if $\widetilde H$ and $H$ are closed subgroups, their Lie algebra are isomorphic.

Comment: thank you, but can you give some more details on why discrete kernel implies isomorphism of lie algebras?

Comment: because it is a covering

Comment: thank you again, i ve missed that you assumed $\widetilde{H}$ and $H$ to be lie groups, but unfortunately, i'm interested in the case if they are not